Cross join and Alias in SQL
I want to understand why mySQL says there's an error in the syntax when I try to run this query:
select g1.*, g2.* 
from (select * from Customer where referee_id is not null) Logs g1, Logs g2

Am I not allowed to alias Logs as g1 and g2?
Edit:
I came across this question on a coding platform. A table was given. The table had information regarding the scores of participants in events. A participant could participate multiple times in the same event. I don't have the original table. But the given table was similar to this:



event_id
participant_name
score




1
Jack
9.8


1
Jones
9.7


2
Jill
9.6


3
Jack
9.9


1
Jack
9.5


4
Jean
9.1


4
Jean
9.4


1
Musk
8.6


2
Dusk
8.5


4
Dusk
9.1


2
Ram
7


2
Sam
8.5


2
Dusk
8.8


3
Amy
9.9


4
Amy
9.1


4
Ram
9.1



So we need to find the top three individual scorers for each event in the following format:



event_id
first
second
third




1
Jack
Jones
Musk


2
Jill
Dusk
Sam


3
Amy,Jack




4
Jean
Amy,Dusk,Ram




I wrote the following query:
with main_table as (select event_id, participant_name, max(score) as score
from scoretable 
group by event_id, participant_name)

SELECT event_id, group_concat(participant_name order by participant_name) as participant_name, ranking from
(select * from 
    (select main_table.*,
     dense_rank() over(partition by event_id order by score desc) as 
     ranking 
     from main_table) main_table2 
where ranking = 1 or ranking = 2 or ranking = 3) main_table3 
group by event_id, ranking

The above query gave the following table:



event_id
participant_name
ranking




1
Jack
1


1
Jones
2


1
Musk
3


2
Jill
1


2
Dusk
2


2
Sam
3


3
Amy,Jack
1


4
Jean
1


4
Amy,Dusk,Ram
2



So I wanted to know if there was a way of turning the above table into the required result format. I thought if I could cross join the table on itself (based on a.event_id = b.event.id = c.event_id and a.ranking < b.ranking < c.ranking
Fomr)so that we have the following table, then I would get the output.



a.event_id
a.participant_name
a.ranking
b.participant_name
b.ranking
c.participant_name
c.ranking




1
Jack
1
Jones
2
Musk
3


2
Jill
1
Dusk
2
Sam
3


3
Amy,Jack
1






4
Jean
1
Amy,Dusk,Ram






From the above table, I can extract event_id, a.participant_name, b.participant_name, c.participant_name and it is done.
So I was wondering on how to cross join the resultant table of my query to itself. Thought of taking it as a derived table and then aliasing it again to cross join.

I know that the query I wrote can probably be written in a better way. I welcome suggestions on how to better write that query.
Also, I want to know how to extend the query I wrote using cross join so as to get the desired result.

Thanks!

Why don't you try it out and see if it works... If it does not work, then you are not allowed to do it. Considering that logs is a derived table, I would not expect this syntax to work.

What are you imagining this (some subquery) Logs g1 is going to do? A subquery gets an Alias, but you are trying to give it two aliases? Please clarify by providing sample data and desired results so we can understand what you are trying to achieve and we aren't left trying to backwards engineer your very wrong sql.

I am sure it will generate syntax error.  You can't write whatever you want, and expect MySQL to understand what you want.

No attempt has been made to bring clarity to this question. The answers are guesses at what OP is wanting and I suspect @jarlh is on the right track, but it's still a guess. I'm voting to close this question as it feels like a drive-by shooting.

Am I not allowed to alias Logs as g1 and g2? You are not allowed to create an alias of an alias. Logs is an alias of the subquery, and you want to re-alias it which is incorrect.

But I want to cross join the subquery with itself. So how do I do it without CTE's @Akina

You cannot use it twice in subquery form w/o CTE, you'd use 2 separate subqueries. From the other side I do not see the reason for the subquery usage, select * from Customer t1 CROSS JOIN Customer t2 where t1.referee_id is not null AND t2.referee_id is not null; should be the most optimal.

Perhaps you want a WITH clause (a.k.a. a cte), to cross join.
WITH Logs AS (
  select * from Customer where referee_id is not null)
select g1.*, g2.* 
from Logs g1, Logs g2

But I'd rather use the explicit CROSS JOIN syntax:
WITH Logs AS (
  select * from Customer where referee_id is not null)
select g1.*, g2.* 
from Logs g1 CROSS JOIN Logs g2


In your current query:
select g1.*, g2.* 
from (select * from Customer where referee_id is not null) Logs g1, Logs g2

It is not clear what Logs g1 is supposed to mean.  A table alias in MySQL is a single term/word following either a table name or a subquery (...).  In your case, you have a subquery on the Customer table, so this version might make sense:
select g1.*, g2.* 
from (select * from Customer where referee_id is not null) g1, Logs g2

Note that if your original goal were a cross join of the Logs table with itself, then you would use the following query:
select g1.*, g2.* 
from Logs g1, Logs g2


Perhaps OP wants a WITH clause?

Sharp eye, I didn't see that...but you said it first so I won't add to my answer.

@TimBiegeleisen Could you please go through my edited question and help me?

You should ask a new question, this one has been closed.
